# Urls amigáveis com flask

Tags: python, url-amigável, flask

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um sistema utilizando o framework python Flask e gostaria de saber como eu posso criar urls amigáveis para o sistema?
Tenho que utilizar algum outro framework ou coisa do tipo?

Answer (score 1):

URL amigável é apena um termo para uma URL padronizada que geralmente é mais fácil de e intuitiva ao usuário final, o objetivo do Flask é este mesmo, escrever URLs como desejar sem precisar de mais nada, assim como a maioria dos frameworks web, então basta entender o conceito básico, isto seria uma URL amigável:

```
http://site/usuario/joao
```

Isto já **não** seria uma URL amigável (ou pelo menos não tão amigável):

```
http://site/channel/UC2hxYQtGLEkcOMK4h8JRycA
```

Isto seria uma URL amigável

```
http://site/channel/stackoverflow
```

Isto já **não** seria uma URL amigável:

```
http://site/?pag=channel&id=stackoverflow
```

Alguns exemplos de URL amigável ao usuário seria algo como:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/") # acessivel via http://site/
def home():
    return "Olá mundo!"

@app.route("/sobre") # acessivel via http://site/sobre
def sobre():
    return "Somos uma empresa!"

@app.route("/contato") # acessivel via http://site/contato
def contato():
    return "Fale conosco!"

@app.route("/foo/bar/baz") # acessivel via http://site/foo/bar/baz
def hello():
    return "Fale conosco!"
```

Mais detalhes em http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#routing

Agora um exemplo de URLs dinâmicas:

1. Exibir um nome digitado na URL como `http://site/usuario/joão` ou `http://site/usuario/mario`

   ```
   @app.route('/usuario/<user>')
   def exibir_perfil(user):
       return 'Usuário %s' % user
   ```
2. Exibir um nome digitado na URL como `http://site/postagem/123` ou `http://site/postagem/456`

   ```
   @app.route('/postagem/<int:id>')
   def exibir_postagem(id):
       return 'Postagem %s' % id
   ```

Se quiser limitar por métodos HTTP, por exemplo:

1. Somente via `GET`:

   ```
   @app.route('/foo/bar', methods=['GET'])
   ```
2. Somente via `POST`:

   ```
   @app.route('/foo/bar', methods=['POST'])
   ```
3. Somente via `HEAD`:

   ```
   @app.route('/foo/bar', methods=['HEAD'])
   ```
4. Somente via `GET` e `POST`:

   ```
   @app.route('/foo/bar', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   ```